# What is the decree of Toledo (תקנות הנישואין של קהל טוליטולה)?

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage, death, estates-inheritance

What is the decree of Toledo? I am not understanding it (I am not good with reading Hebrew). Something to do with the wife inheriting (half of) her husband's property? (I always thought she does not inherit him at all.)

Please explain the decree in general (and some details), and if it is binding today.

Sources:

https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Even_HaEzer.118.1

and תקנת טוליטולה here:

https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Even_HaEzer.90.1

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=3931) (Hebrew) contains a nice explanation in its introduction. Here is a summary in my own words:

> A woman does not (on a biblical level) inherit from her husband. However, she is entitled to claim her
>   *ketubah*-obligations from his estate. If the husband had obligated himself in a particularly large *ketubah*, this could mean that she
>   takes the entirety of the estate, leaving nothing for the children to inherit.
>
> To counteract this, the community of Toledo enacted that a woman could
>   only claim her *ketubah* up to half of the value of the estate, even if the amount stipulated in the *ketubah* was greater than this.

The article claims that this enactment was adopted by the majority of Jewish communities, and then goes on to discuss its applicability under (secular) Israeli law today.